# CudaMemcpy of a single bool takes way too long

Tags: cuda

I am writing K-means clustering on CUDA and I run to a very weird problem. I need to set a bool to false at the beginning of clustering iteration and then read it back. However, the `memcpy` of bool takes waaaaaaay too long compared to other stuff, see the graph.

Yellow (top-most) **~3 ms**: Initial cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy of all data (about 7MB of floats), total 6 arrays.

Red **~2 ms**: Copy of a single boolean

Blue **~10 ms**: Clustering itself

Green **~4 ms**: Parallel reduction - summation of a per-thread result to one result (about 20 kernel invocations on average)

Purple/brown **< 1 ms**: cudaFree

[image: Graph of times]

The code itself looks like this:

```
bool changed = false;
...
float start = sdkGetTimerValue(&stopWatch);
cudaMemcpy(dev_changed, &changed, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
float end = sdkGetTimerValue(&stopWatch);
...
```

For time measurement I am using TimerHelper.h from CUDA examples that internally uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` for time measurement. I checked the time measurement about 10 times because I could not believe this. If I take the cudaMemcpy out, the tome goes near to 0 (unlike 2 ms).

The bizarre thing is when I compared the boolean copy times (red) with Parallel reduction (green) which is 1 `memcpy` vs. 20 kernel invocations.

So I tried to write a kernel that just sets the bool to false:

```
__global__ void SetToFalse(bool* boolean) {
    boolean[0] = false;
}

void LaunchSetToFalse(bool* boolean) {
    SetToFalse<<<1, 1>>>(boolean);
}
```

And then changed the code to:

```
...
float start = sdkGetTimerValue(&stopWatch);
LaunchSetToFalse(dev_changed);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
float end = sdkGetTimerValue(&stopWatch);
...
```

But it still takes about ~2ms (no change).

Am I missing something obvious? What makes the bool copy so slow? Also, the green contains copying of the boolean from GPU to CPU and it takes about half of the green block. I very carefully checked the time measurement and there should not be any error; however, the results are so weird.

Is there any better way how to report a bool from threads? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: Here is bigger chunk of the code:

```
cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_data, data.getRawSize() * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_linearizedClusterCenters, clustersCount * size_dim * sizeof(float)); 
cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_outClusters, rowsCount * sizeof(byte));

cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_changed, sizeof(bool));
cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_count, numOfThreadBlocks * clustersCount * sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_newData, numOfThreadBlocks * clustersCount * size_dim * sizeof(float));

cudaMemcpy(dev_data, data.getDataPointer() , data.getRawSize() * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_outClusters, outClusters , rowsCount * sizeof(byte), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_linearizedClusterCenters, inOutLinearizedClusterCenters , clustersCount * size_dim  * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

perfRecorder.endInit();
for (int global_count = 0; (global_count < maxIterations) && changed[0]; global_count++) {
    perfRecorder.startIteration();
    /* <<<<<<<<<< THIS GUY TAKES WAY TOO LONG >>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
    changed[0] = false;
    cudaMemcpy(dev_changed, changed, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //LaunchSetToFalse(dev_changed);
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    perfRecorder.startIterationCompute();
    LaunchKernel(dev_data, dev_linearizedClusterCenters, dev_outClusters, dev_changed, dev_count, dev_newData, clustersCount, size_dim, rowsCount, numOfThreads, numOfBlocks);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    perfRecorder.endIterationCompute();
    cudaMemcpy(changed, dev_changed, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    LaunchParallelSummationInt(dev_count, numOfThreadBlocks * clustersCount, numOfThreads,
        parallelReductionIterations);
    LaunchParallelSummationFloat(dev_newData, numOfThreadBlocks * clustersCount * size_dim, numOfThreads,
        parallelReductionIterations);
    LaunchCountNewClusterCenters(dev_newData, dev_count, clustersCount, size_dim, dev_linearizedClusterCenters, numOfThreads);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();  // <<<<<<< EDIT 2
    perfRecorder.endIteration();
}// End of for

perfRecorder.startCleanup();
cudaMemcpy(outClusters, dev_outClusters, rowsCount * sizeof(byte), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(dev_data);
cudaFree(dev_linearizedClusterCenters);
cudaFree(dev_outClusters);

cudaFree(dev_changed);
cudaFree(dev_count);
cudaFree(dev_newData);
perfRecorder.endCleanup();
```

EDIT 2: As @Robert Crovella correctly suggested, I put sync just before `perfRecorder.endIteration();`. The graph got better but still, transfer of 1 byte takes quite a bit of time (~1 ms):

[image: Bench after sync]

EDIT 3: I am using Windows and the timing code just saves the number of milliseconds as a float and then subtracts them. I am ignoring the delay of the stopwatch.

```
/****** Code from NVIDIA sample code in TimeHelper.h ******/
inline float StopWatchWin::getTime() {
    // Return the TOTAL time to date
    float retval = total_time;
    if (running) {
        LARGE_INTEGER temp;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &temp);
        retval += (float)(((double)(temp.QuadPart - start_time.QuadPart)) / freq);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: linux or windows?  what code (exactly) precedes the `cudaMemcpy` ?  The `cudaMemcpy` (or equivalently, a kernel) would have to wait until all previous cuda operations in the stream are complete.  Are you issuing any async or kernel calls previous to the `cudaMemcpy`?  Unfortunately, the code you've omitted from your description probably matters.

Comment: @Robert Crovella - Thanks for the comment, I posted larger chunk of the code. But what you say makes kind of sense - could it be that the memcpy actually waits for the `LaunchCountNewClusterCenters` kernel? So I am actually measuring that? It is also weird because that operation should be very very fast as well (~100 threads doing two divisions).

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening.  To prove it, place a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` right before the `perfRecorder.endIteration();` line.  If you don't have any synchronization along the way, you may even be waiting for kernels prior to `LaunchCountNewClusterCenters`.  Kernel calls are asynchronous.  Any timing code that comes immediately after a kernel call, with no intervening synchronization, is likely to produce confusing results.  This is especially true when using a host-based timing function like `QueryPerformanceCounter`, instead of `cudaEvent` based timing.

Comment: @Robert Crovella - You are absolutely right, I did that but still, it takes more than I would think. Is that just overhead of memcpy?

Comment: I'm sure you're capable of discovering what the duration of that `cudaMemcpy` should be.  There's much of your code you haven't shown, such as the timing code, yet you want me to explain your timing results?  Here's [my attempt](http://pastebin.com/bjnMN0Ai) at discovering what the duration of that `cudaMemcpy` operation should be (linux).  You still haven't answered my question about linux or windows.  Windows (WDDM) can skew performance data for a variety of reasons, one of which is that cuda operations can get batched.

Comment: @Robert Crovella - That's the reason of my question. The memcpy of bool should be blazingly fast... I included a piece of code of the time measurement. Btw, thanks for the comments!

Comment: I spent a whole chapter of The CUDA Handbook basically talking about the CPU overhead of memcpy's. (Chapter 6)  CUDA takes thousands of clock cycles to kick off a memcpy.  The special kernel to clear the device memory variable didn't help because CUDA kernels also are expensive to launch. Using cudaMemcpyAsync() instead of cudaMemcpy() might enable you to hide some of the CPU overhead.  But if the data's shared between CPU and GPU, I would advise you allocate changed in mapped pinned memory instead.  Then your code can examine or set the variable without explicit copying.